# Bootstrap 3 Modal Overflow iPhone Bug?

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I have this weird problem that I can only find on the iPhone's Safari browser.

A specific modal element has a strange overlay effect.

I'm not sure if this happens on Android smartphones; my Android tablet atleast does not have this issue.

Is this a common bug? Why does this only happen to the iPhone?

Bug in action:[image]

Website: https://titomagic.com

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: If you see on the image I linked at the end of my post, triggering the modal doesn't make it fully show. The overlay is kinda bugged.

Comment: The bug seems to show up specifically for the iPhone